# Data Loader, export process

Tags: soql, data-loader

i need to export 19,00,000 records from the production. i started the process but in the middle due to network issue the process failed. and export file having only some of the records from where was the issue raised, 
so i need to export rest of the records.. HOW?

Comment: cant you export one more time?

Comment: Considering the size of data I would restrict myself from using data loader because of API calls it would make. Using Standard Weekly Data export seems like best approach.
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_exportdata.htm&type=5

Answer (score 2):

You can reexport the records from the beginning by using dataloader with Bulk API option, it will hardly take 2-3 minutes max to export all 1.9M records.

Otherwise, in the dataloader settings you can specify starting row from which it can be exported the rest of the records.

Answer (score 1):

Next time consider chunking the queries in smaller batches using the createddate range as a scope.  So next time you fail due to network issues it will only impact that batch.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Data Loader, maybe you can try other third-party tools, such as [Acho](http://acho.io/), to bulk export data. Although it still takes time to retrieve data, the process runs on cloud so you don't need to worry about the network issue.